# Combining varargs and higher order functions

Tags: scala

Trying to use varargs with higher order functions. But the below doesn't seem to type/compile.

```
def f(n: Any*) = {...} //compiles
def f(fun: Any* => Any) = {...} // doesn't compile
```

Is there anyway to use varargs this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work

```
def f(fun: (Any*) => Any) = {...}
```

Comment: Huh - that does work. I actually tried that initially and using it but intellij was giving me some 'errors' with the application but turns it does compile. Thanks!